# Xcode autolayout guidelines do not appear

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, autolayout

When you drag a new view into a view controller in the storyboard dotted blue guidelines are supposed to appear, which help to position the view and apply autolayout constraints.

[Dotted blue guidelines](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2/guides)

In my case these guides do not appear, no matter where I move the view. I must have done something to disable them, but i have no idea what. How can a get the guides back?

I'm using xcode 6.1.1 and autolayout is enabled ( the autolayout checkbox is checked and it seems to be working fine apart from this)

Thanks in advance for any advice you can give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure Editor > Canvas > Snap to Guides is enabled:

[image]